# Presentation of the Monster as a Hurwitz group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

The Monster group is the largest of the sporadic simple groups, and has been proven by Wilson to also be a Hurwitz group. It has a presentation in terms of Coxeter groups, specifically Y443 along with the "spider" relator, and quotienting out by the center. However, I am interested in a presentation as a Hurwitz group.

Specifically, what is a presentation of the monster in terms of two elements a and b such that a has order 2, b has order 3, and ab has order 7? Also, what is the smallest possible order of the commutator of a and b in such a presentation?

Comment: It doesn't look like this is known, at least none of the papers citing Wilson's paper seem to do it.  I'm not an expert though so I suppose I could have missed something.

Comment: I would guess that it would be possible to compute such a presentation by applying a standard change of generator algorithm to the existing presentation, although the resulting presentation would be unlikely to be particularly illuminating. To do that you would need to be able to do basic computations with elements of the Minster, but that is possible - Wilson  has software for that. Wilson would also be the best person to ask about the minimal order of $[a,b]$.

Comment: Actually, the last question does not depend on a presentation, but just on a generating subset $(a,b)$ satisfying the $(2,3,7)$ relations (presentation refers to an explicit set of relations). Whether there's a "short" presentation is  intriguing, anyway.

Comment: I suppose such a presentation gives a closed surface with the Monster group acting on it, but it will be pretty big.

Comment: A related question: is there a presentation by three involutions whose products have order 2, 3, and 7 respectively?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have computed two pairs of generators $(a,b)$ of the Monster satisfying
the relations  $a^2 = b^3 = (ab)^7 = 1$ using [1]. In both cases $a$ is of
class 2B, $b$ is of class 3B in the Monster, and the commutator $[a, b]$
has order 39. This gives an upper bound for the minimal order of that commutator.
More details of the computation are given in subdirectory
`applications/Hurwitz` of [1].

[1] Martin Seysen, the  python mmgroup package,

https://github.com/Martin-Seysen/mmgroup

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! I've had a look through the comments on the github package, that does seem to take quite a while to find a Hurwitz generating set. Are calculations for that sill ongoing? I'd be keen to see if there are other possible generator pairs, with a different order of the commutator.

Comment: Computations are still ongoing. I expect to find about one pair per week, and a friend       of mine may find about one pair per day with a faster computer. I have not yet looked for pairs $(a,b)$ of classes (2B, 3C), which may exist according to  the paper *The Monster is a Hurwitz group* by  R.A. Wilson,

Comment: Have any new pairs been found? @Martin Seysen

Comment: Altogether I found 5 pairs  pairs $(a,b)$ of classes (2B, 3B). The commutator has order 39 in all cases.